# Aspects not working with Spliterator (Stream Api)

Tags: java-8, aspectj, java-stream, spliterator

I try to watch my spliterator with AspectJ aspects for logging purpose. However it seems impossible. The aspect never gets called and IntelliJ tell me that the advice advices no method. Im using AspectJ 1.8.1.

You'll find a SSCCE at github: https://github.com/flaviait/StreamSpliteratorAspectJExample

Spliterator with annotated aspect:

```
public class RepositorySpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    @Override
    @SpliteratorWatch
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SpliteratorWatchAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpliteratorWatchAspect.class);

    @After("@annotation(spliteratorWatch)")
    public void watch(JoinPoint joinPoint, SpliteratorWatch spliteratorWatch) throws Throwable {
        ...
    }

}
```

And last but not least the Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SpliteratorWatch {
}
```

I did this serveral times in different contexts and it works fine. Is there any known issue with the Java 8 stream api, spliterators and aspects? Maybe someone can help me. That would be great!

Comment: Please, specify what exactly isn't working. Does the advice code get correctly weaved?

Comment: Oh gosh, sorry. I updated my request. However I cant tell you much more about the issue.

Comment: Are you using a Java 8-aware version of AspectJ, if not the most recent? It’s always a good idea to include version numbers into such a question.

Comment: Oh sorry.. Good advice. I edit my request. Im using AspectJ 1.8.1

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you provide a minimal, fully self-consistent code sample, optimally a Maven project on GitHub? An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) makes the problem reproduceable.

Comment: Yep ok i'll create one :)

Comment: Created a SSCCE and changed my request

Comment: I’m not an `AspectJ` expert but shouldn’t the spelling of `@annotation(spliteratorWatch)` match the annotation type `SpliteratorWatch`? Or is that case insensitive?

Comment: yep, it matches the annotation type :)